# Popup Message instead of lblMessage

Tags: asp.net

I want show this "lblMessage.Text = "Message sent successfully.";" message in a popup upon Clicking on the submit button. How do i do that in asp.net?

Comment: I'm assuming you want this popup after the action of the submit button has completed.

Comment: There are several ways to do that But you have to be more specific about your design and problem.? can you put on some screenshot or code so that it may be more helpful in this scenario

Comment: Javascript is still your friend in ASP.Net.

Comment: Do you want this alert all the time or only if the message is actually sent? Do you have existing code that is setting the label and now, instead of that, you want an alert?

Answer (score 0):

Change the text after hiding all the form. Choose an update panel where it will update asynchronously and after the completion of the event replace it with a label and set the text to message sent succesfully. Thats what i can understand from the description. If you can provide your scenario it would be more helpful. or if you want to show a popup message then this [would be helpful](http://forums.asp.net/t/1461308.aspx/1)